# How to specify an attribute common to all factories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

Rails database tables usually have timestamps (`created_at` and `updated_at`) and, as of rails 4, all timestamp columns have `NOT NULL` constraints.  Therefore, all factories must specify values for said timestamps.  How can I specify an attribute common to all factories, without repeating myself?

Something similar was discussed in [issue 564](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/564).

I could use [instance_eval](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) like this:

```
module SharedFactoryBits
  def self.timestamps
    Proc.new {
      created_at { Time.zone.now }
      updated_at { Time.zone.now }
    }
  end
end

# spec/factories/banana_factory.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :banana do
    instance_eval &SharedFactoryBits.timestamps
  end
end

# spec/factories/kiwi_factory.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :kiwi do
    instance_eval &SharedFactoryBits.timestamps
  end
end
```

but it's not very legible.

I am using:

```
gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.2.1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you need to specify the timestamps? Even though they are fields with `NOT NULL` constraints, their absence does not affect validation, as Rails applies those at the time of insert or update. I don't have them specified on any of my Rails 4 apps, and those factories all pass a validity test.

Is your question about other common attributes, or are you specifically concerned with timestamps? If it's the latter, I think you can skip all this work.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, I was only concerned with timestamps, and it looks like I don't need them in my factories.  I had a failing test telling me that the `not null` constraint of a `created_at` column was violated, and I thought it was the factory's fault, but that was a red herring.